# CakePHP Login in Jquery Gives Blackhole Error

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 2 along with the Users plugin.

I have a link that, when clicked on, shows a jquery box with the login form inside. The Jquery works find, but when I submit the form that's inside the Jquery box, I get the following error: "The request has been black-holed".

Here's my code:

```
<div id="dropdown-container">
    <div id="topnav"class="topnav"><a href="login" class="signin"><span>Sign in</span></a> </div>
        <fieldset id="signin_menu">
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->create('Users.user', array(
                    'action' => 'login',
                    'id' => 'LoginForm'));
                echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                    'label' => __d('users', 'Email')));
                echo $this->Form->input('password',  array(
                    'label' => __d('users', 'Password')));

                echo '<p>' . __d('users', 'Remember Me') . $this->Form->checkbox('remember_me') . '</p>';
                echo '<p>' . $this->Html->link(__d('users', 'I forgot my password'), array('action' => 'reset_password')) . '</p>';

                echo $this->Form->hidden('User.return_to', array('value' => '/'));
                echo $this->Form->end(__d('users', 'Submit'));
            ?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".signin").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("fieldset#signin_menu").toggle();
            $(".signin").toggleClass("menu-open");
        });

        $("fieldset#signin_menu").mouseup(function() {
            return false
        });
        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            if($(e.target).parent("a.signin").length==0) {
                $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
                $("fieldset#signin_menu").hide();
            }
        });         

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the [CSRF](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#csrf-configuration) extension? If so, check out the actual generated source code and look in the `form` tag for hidden inputs with the names `data[_Token][key]` and `data[_Token][fields]`data[_Token][unlocked]` (think that should be it..) -> make sure you send them as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cakeDC users plugin gets blackholed with register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418889/cakedc-users-plugin-gets-blackholed-with-register)

Comment: See the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418889/cakedc-users-plugin-gets-blackholed-with-register